# Cropping image with WPF using MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30725/Cropping-Images

This article explains how to crop image using code behind, but I want to use View model and commands to crop image. Is this achievable?

I'm not sure how to send (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) to command.

Comment: Add `Button` in your view & Bind a `ViewModel Command` to it & pass this image as a `Command Parameter`...

Comment: @AmolBavannavar but how do I pass mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late answering this question but i'm also trying to create an image cropper application using mvvm. I'm not an expert and still new with WPF and MVVM but in order for me to send mouseevents like mouseleftbuttondown, mousemove, mouseleftbuttonup to view I use eventtriggers from expression blend. In view, I assign or name an event trigger of my choice and bind a command to the appropriate control. In my application i have a canvas with a rectangle child inside a Grid which also holds the image. The user imports an image and draws a rectangle on the image to crop it which is achieved by using mouse events. I bind the command in my grid which when someone acts upon the events I implemented (mouseleftbuttondown/up, mousemove) anywhere in the grid it will fire the trigger. Here is how it looks in xaml (or part of its since I'm not finished yet):

```
    <Grid x:Name="GridLoadedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <Image x:Name="LoadedImage" Margin="10" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                <Canvas  x:Name="BackPanel" Margin="10">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="selectionRectangle"  Stroke="LightBlue" Fill="#220000FF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

I'm currently in the process of putting together the coding in my view model which I plan to have the function command for all three mouseevent. If you plan on using event triggers you would need to add the statement below in your mainwindow xaml

```
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

You would also need to install Expression Blend SDK. I have nuget package manager installed and I used it to install expression blend. Hope this helps

Comment: I am looking for something similar, did you finish your implementation?